# Is there a gem that will notify when JOIN/WHERE query is used on column(s) without an index in Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, activerecord

Is there a Ruby gem or PostgreSQL extension that would notify when `JOIN` or `WHERE` query is used on column(s) without an index?

Comment: Not directly, but you can use `auto_explain` and `pg_stat_statements` to help. Don't assume that a seqscan is bad or that indexes are always good though; you need to learn about selectivity, index costs, etc.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks. The reason I'm asking is that we've got a few tables that have a few millions rows and we've already had issues in production, where a specific query took really long time to complete and was slowing down the whole database. I understand that it's hard to make a perfect tool for that, but it would be awesome if there was something that could at least let you know when something *might* cause such issues and would run when e.g. executing tests.

Comment: Yes, it'd be interesting to have tooling that compared test queries to minimum runtimes, captured auto_explain data, etc. Interesting project, but harder than you'd think to get to produce a useful false positive rate.